# Can't change to Korean-named directory on my debian server

Tags: ssh, debian

I made a *rsync* backup of some directories from a macbook laptop to a debian server. Some of these have korean characters (*Hangeul*) in their names. After fixing my server's locale, it displays well when I do a *ls* for instance. But I can't *cd* to it.

Example:

```
$ ls -1 | head
한국어
dirA
dirB
…
```

But if try to go browse that directory:

```
$ cd 한 국 어
cd: 3: can't cd to 한국어
```

Any idea what's wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you try cheating, either with TAB-completion, or by putting only the first character then a `*`?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Everything else in the directory start with a regular (roman) letter?  How about `cd [^A-z]*`?

Comment: That works. Dirty hack though. And how to do if I have several directories starting with non-roman letters ?

Comment: You can have some invisible symbols in your directory name. I see your `cd 한 국 어` has spaces between the Korean characters which is probably not what you want. What does `LANG=C ls -b` show as the name of your directory?

Comment: Here's what I get : `\341\204\222\341\205\241\341\206\253\341\204\200\341\205\256\341\206\250\341\204\213\341\205\245`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest entering `ls -il | egrep "^[0-9]+ d"` to get the index number `xxxxxxxx` (first field of the output) of the badly named directory, followed by something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -inum xxxxxxxx -exec /bin/mv {} NewDirectoryName \;` to change the directory name to something that won't cause problems in the future.

Comment: General solution, but still a workaround.
Based on your comment I did this: `cd $(find . -maxdepth 1 -inum xxxxxxxx)`
But it would be good to fix the input issue rather than finding workarounds.